# Python: Reference an object attribute by variable name?

Tags: python, oop

I'm programming the board game Monopoly in Python.  Monopoly has three types of land that the player can buy: properties (like Boardwalk), railroads, and utilities.  Properties have a variable purchase price and rents for 6 conditions (0-4 houses, or a hotel).  Railroads and utilities have a fixed price and rents based on how many other railroads or utilities you own.

I have a Game() class that contains three dictionary attributes, all whose key is the land parcel's position on the board from 0-39:

- .properties, whose values are a list containing the space's name, buy price, color group and rents (tuple);
- .railroads, which consists only of the space name;
- .utilities, also containing only the space name.

I did this because at certain points I want to iterate over the appropriate dictionary to see if the player owns other parcels of land in that dictionary; and also because the number of values differs.

Game() also has a tuple called space_types, where each value is a number representing a type of space (property, railroad, utility, luxury tax, GO, etc.).  To find out what kind of space_type my player is sitting on:

`space_type = space_types[boardposition]`

I also have a Player() class with a method buy_property(), which contains a print statement that should say:

`"You bought PropertyName for $400."`

where PropertyName is the name of the space.  But right now I have to use an if/elif/else block like so, which seems ugly:

```
    space_type = Game(space_types[board_position])
    if space_type is "property":
         # pull PropertyName from Game.properties
    elif space_type is "railroad":
         # pull PropertyName from Game.railroads
    elif space_type is "utility":
         # pull PropertyName from Game.utilities
    else:
         # error, something weird has happened
```

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
    dictname = "dictionary to pull from"  # based on space_type
    PropertyName = Game.dictname  # except .dictname would be "dictionary to pull from"
```

Is it possible in Python to pass the value of a variable as the name of an attribute to be referenced?  I will also appreciate someone telling me I'm approaching this fundamentally wrong and suggesting a better way to go about it.

Comment: "Is it possible in Python to pass the value of a variable as the name of an attribute to be referenced?" - Why not use another layer of dictionary?

Comment: As an aside, using `"apple" is "apple"` is not necessarily guaranteed to succeed, because strings aren't guaranteed to be the same object. (`is` compares by object identity [if they are *exactly* the same object], whereas `==` compares their equality.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `getattr` function:

```
property_name = getattr(Game, dictname)
```

Comment: Crazy logic, simple answer.  That looks like what I need.  Pays to read the docs thoroughly!

Answer (score 8):

Use the `getattr` built-in:

```
PropertyName = getattr(Game, dictname)
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr

Answer (score 2):

How about a dictionary of dictionaries?

```
D= {"property": Game.properties, "railroad": Game.railroads, "utility": Game.utilities}
space_type = Game(space_types[board_position])
dictname = D[space_type]
```

Comment: Learned another new thing.  I should have done that from the beginning and may re-structure my dictionaries later on.  Thank you!